# Importing blob data from RDBMS (Sybase) to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to import large blob data ( around 10 TB ) from an RDBMS (Sybase ASE) into Cassandra, using DataStax Enterprise(DSE) 5.0 .

Is sqoop still the recommended way to do this in DSE 5.0? As per the release notes(http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html) :

> Hadoop and Sqoop are deprecated. Use Spark instead. (DSP-7848)

So should I use Spark SQL with JDBC data source to load data from Sybase, and then save the data frame to a Cassandra table?

Is there a better way to do this? Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: As per DSE documentation (http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkIntro.html), writing to blob columns from spark is not supported.

> The following Spark features and APIs are not supported:
>
> Writing to blob columns from Spark
>
> Reading columns of all types is supported; however, you must convert collections of blobs to byte arrays before serialising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark for the ETL of large data sets is preferred because it performs a distributed injest.  Oracle data can be loaded into Spark RDDs or data frames and then just use saveToCassandra(keyspace, tablename).  Cassandra Summit 2016 had a presentation [Using Spark to Load Oracle Data into Cassandra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsXBFDPGDLo) by Jim Hatcher which discusses this topic in depth and provides examples.

Sqoop is deprecated but should still work in DSE 5.0. If its a one-time load and you're already confortable with Squoop, try that.

Comment: Thanks. I have used spark for ETL / to load data into HDFS. But it seems writing blob columns from spark is not supported in DSE 5.0. This is a one time load, so I would probably use sqoop.